# Installing mysql with mysql-apt-config: missing keys

Tags: debian, mysql

I'm trying to update mysql on my Debian server with `mysq-apt-config`, but whenever I try to update it with `dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb` I get a missing keys error.

```
> dpkg -i /tmp/mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
(Reading database ... 54485 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.11-1) over (0.8.11-1) ...
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.11-1) ...
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package mysql-apt-config)
key 8C718D3B5072E1F5:
75 signatures not checked due to missing keys
OK
```

I already have 8.0.3-rc installed, but I want the latest version. How do I solve this?

```
> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.3-rc for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
Release:        9.6
Codename:       stretch
```

Answer (score 2):

Add missing key to your key ring :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5
```

And try installation once again:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/mysql-apt-config*.deb
```